# after uploading sample data into magento I can't log in

Tags: magento, localhost, wamp

"Invalid User Name or Password." i try resetting the password but the email doesn't go through. I inserted the login details on the database & it still doesn't allow me to login. Please help.

Comment: you are try to login in admin panel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query (in php myadmin)

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('NEWPASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'ADMINUSERNAME';
```

Try to delete  everything inside var folder

\magento\var\

Comment: I have updated it gave another error which is "Access denied", Yes I am trying to log in the admin panel

Comment: give permission to all project folders and enclosed files

Comment: after deleting everything I got "There has been an error processing your request." I aslo gave all my project folders permission. still no difference.

Comment: check there is a maintenance file is in root.delete that file also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the script for creating a new Admin user: 
https://gist.github.com/litzinger/48be5876d6bba1509323

Next, you can restore your user from the Admin panel, and delete the one you don't need.

If the error is triggered by the issue with the frontend user, it's OK. The point is that Magento uses sample data to fill in the Users table. In this case, you should restore your database from the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

open file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php

find function named

```
authenticate($username, $password)
```

and put

```
return true;
```

after following statement

```
$this->loadByUsername($username);
```

after that user your administartor user's username and anything in password, and try logging in. After successful Login change password from inside admin pannel.